# If a difference of two sequences diverges to $+ \infty$ then their sum also diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $t_n > s_n$ be two sequences such that $t_n - s_n \to +\infty$. Then $t_n + s_n$ also diverges?

Comment: How about $t_n = n$, $s_n = -n$?

Comment: This works only if you add that $s_n$ (thus also $t_n$) is nonnegative.

Comment: If you assume that $s_n$ is nonnegative, as mentioned by Oscar Lanzi, then for $t_n-s_n$ to diverge to positive infinity, $t_n$ must diverge, and diverge “faster” than $s_n$. For a special case where both sequences can be written as $a_0(r)^n$, they diverge if $r>1$ and $a_0>0$. Even if $s_n$ is constant, $t_n$ must diverge if $t_n-s_n$ is to be greater than $0$. So then, no matter what $s_n$ does (except being negative), $t_n+s_n$ diverges.